# Is there a Dojo naming convention for classes?

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs

Dojo [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html) is using `"/"` to declare a hierarchy between classes.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare){
  return declare(null, {
    constructor: function(name, age, residence){
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.residence = residence;
    }
  });
});

require(["my/Person"], function(Person){
  var folk = new Person("phiggins", 42, "Tennessee");
});
```

But I found some code with `my.Person` instead of `/` and Webstorm Structure View is able to order classes when we use the `.`.

Do we have any naming convention for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot `(.)` separated pkg are used in version prior to 1.7 , in v > 1.7 its being replaced by slash (`/`)

`require` replace the `dojo.require` wich comes with those change .

If you read the [Migration guide](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/migration-17.html) between 1.x and 1.7 you can see :

> dojo.require takes a **dot-separated** module name, require() takes a
>   **forward-slash** separated module name

So use only forward-slash for version  1.7 and next ...

Comment: Nice explanation thank you, it's quite interesting! 
I'm working with Dojo 1.10 for maintenance only and I didn't have to change the existing structure of the code.
I'm still surprise to see a working widget in my project named `'app.service.common.widgets.BreadCrumb'` and being used with `'app/service/common/widgets/BreadCrumb'` notation. I guess this is due to the backward compability of the Dojo AMD migration.

Comment: yes , it will work , but I thin there will be some difference between using / or dot , by example they said in debuging that **The most common error for programmers used to the legacy loader API is to express a module identifier using dots instead of slashes**. see [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/loader/amd.html)